# Handle multiple calls to async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await

I have a imported component, she calls a function every time that user do something (lets say press on button), in the function i must to fetch some data in async order, i would like to run the function calls as async way, the calls to the function will wait until the function is finished and then call the function again.
code example- if i trigger the function 3 times fast:

```
hadlechange = async(type:string) => {
  console.log(1111111)
  let storage = await getData("G");
  console.log(22222222)

    await bla1();
    await bla2();
    console.log(333333)

  await storeData('blabla');
  console.log(4444444)
};

render() {
  return (
    <BlaBla onChange ={this.hadlechange}>)
    }
```

**Expected results**

```
11111
22222
3333
4444
1111
2222
3333 
4444
1111
2222
3333 
4444
```

**What i get**

```
1111
1111
2222
2222
1111
3333
2222
4444
3333
3333
4444
4444
```

I use JavaScript- React for the client

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that multiple changes are happening at once. An easy fix is to set a global flag to prevent the event method while the current action is in-progress.

```
constructor() {
   this.notHandling = true;
}

hadlechange = async(type:string) => {
  if (this.notHandling) {
     this.notHandling = false;
     console.log(1111111)
     let storage = await getData("G");
     console.log(22222222)

     await bla1();
     await bla2();
     console.log(333333)

     await storeData('blabla');
     console.log(4444444)
     this.notHandling = true;
  }
};
```

### Edit: Helper class example

```
class AsyncQueue {
    private queue: Function[];
    private processing: boolean;

    constructor() {
        this.queue = [];
        this.processing = false;
    }

    push = (method:any) => {
        this.queue.push(method);
        this.process();
    }

    private process = async () => {
        if (!this.processing) {
           this.processing = true;
           for (let action of this.queue) {
              await action();
           }
           this.processing = false;
        }
    }
}

export const asyncQueue = new AsyncQueue;
```

### Using Helper

```
// import example...
import { asyncQueue } from '~/common/helpers';

// Async test method
const tester = (message: string, seconds: number = 1) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        console.log('start ' + message);
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(message);
            resolve(message);
        }, seconds * 1000);
    });
};

// Method calls
asyncQueue.push(() => tester('FIRST'));
setTimeout(() => asyncQueue.push(() => tester('SECOND', 2)), 50);
asyncQueue.push(() => tester('THIRD', 4));
```

Comment: Thank you for the response but it didn't help me , i want it to fetch the data multiple times - if i will do like this it can fetch it just once..
I want it to wait until the previous calls finish and then call it

Comment: But you want them to fire in sequence, correct?  You can store your requests in a queue (a simple array) to ensure each event fired executes.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Proximo i thought about this solution and it's works fine.
Maybe someone else will find it helpful so i share my code :)

```
  constructor() {
    this.notHandling = true;
    this.saves = [];
  }

  onChange = async (status: string) => {
    this.saves.push(status);
    if (this.notHandling) {
      this.notHandling = false;
      while (saves.length > 0) {
        await blabla1(saves.pop());
         ...
      }
      this.notHandling = true;
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <BlaBla onChange ={this.hadlechange}>)
      }
```

**Edit**

As a help function

```
 export const handleMultiAsyncCalls = func => {
  let notHandling = true;
  let saves = [];
  return async function() {
    const args = arguments;
    const context = this;
    saves.push(args);
    if (notHandling) {
      notHandling = false;
      while (saves.length > 0) {
        await func.apply(context, saves.pop());
      }
      notHandling = true;
    }
  };
};
```

In your class you call it this way-

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleMultiCalls = handleMultiAsyncCalls(blablaFunc);

  handleChange = (data: string) => {
    this.handleMultiCalls(data);
  };
```

Comment: Nicely done, now you can abstract that pattern out as a helper function.

Comment: Cool, are you a C# developer too? Let me show you how I'd do the same in an edit.